# call function in android devices when data updated in mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, server, host

i need some help please.
i have created an android app using android studio. this app is connected to mysql database that located on host server (Hostinger.com) via PHP Files that also located on the same server. so, let's say i have 3 users using this app (User A - User B - User C). "User A" add a new student to the table "Students". **My Question is:** after adding this new student, i want to run automatically a function "refreshData" on the devices of "User B" and "User C" to get the updated data from the server. is that possible? if yes, so, how i can do that? Thank you in advance.
N.B.: i used a timer that is runned every 2 minutes to call this function but i try to find more best solutions instead of this way.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258677/android-listen-for-messages-from-server-socket

Comment: Best to leave mysql out of this since it does not have any notification fetures. Use a solution designed for passing notifications around, siuch as a message queue or redis.